# Why does my codeblock work in main() but not in its own function?

Tags: c

A block of code produces the expected results when placed directly within the body of main(), but not when split off into its own function and called from main().

This is my first real try at C programming. As an exercise, I figured I'd try using ncurses to get an intro screen with centered text. Nice and simple, ncurses did the trick since printf isn't really capable of it.

So, I figure the next step would be to compartmentalize it within its own function as a first step to splitting it off into a separate .c file. I figure this would be a good way to practice splitting up code and referencing via header includes with the prototype in a .h file. Well, I never got that far. The code block simply doesn't do anything when compiled and run as its own function.

By "doesn't do anything" I mean that when I run the compiled program, nothing appears on the screen and I simply get the prompt again.

This is the version that produces the correct results:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

char mesg1[]="Space Tycoon";
char mesg3[]="Press Any Key To Continue";
int row,col;
initscr();
getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);
mvprintw(row/2-1,(col-strlen(mesg1))/2,"%s",mesg1);                                            
mvprintw(row/2+5,(col-strlen(mesg3))/2,"%s",mesg3);                                            
refresh();                                                                               
getch();
endwin();   

return 0;

}
```

...and the version that does not:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

void intro();

void main()
    {
    void intro();
    }

void intro() 
{
    char mesg1[]="Space Tycoon";
    char mesg3[]="Press Any Key To Continue";
    int row,col;
    initscr();
    getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);
    mvprintw(row/2-1,(col-strlen(mesg1))/2,"%s",mesg1);                                            
    mvprintw(row/2+5,(col-strlen(mesg3))/2,"%s",mesg3);                                            
    refresh();                                                                               
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: Inside `main()` this `void intro();` looks like declaration which you already did above `main()`. Change it to `intro();` And since `intro` doesn't expect any input argument, this `void intro(void)` looks proper rather than `void intro();`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Up to you, but I suggest spacing your code a bit more (helpful for older eyes), e.g. `char mesg1[] = "Space Tycoon";` or `getmaxyx (stdscr, row, col);` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(){
    intro();  // not void intro()
}
```

because you want to *call* the `intro` function from your `main`. If you code `void intro();` you just are *declaring* (see C11 §6.7.6.3) inside `main` that `intro` function (and then you'll better give its signature, e.g. write `void intro(void);`).

BTW your main has to return `int`. See C11 specification [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §5.1.2.2.1

Look also into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site.

Comment: Again, thanks. It feels good to finally know why this hasn't worked.

Comment: See [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3) - if the closing `'}'` is reached before a `return n'`, `0` is returned by default (C99+).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's about the missing `return` statement. The return type should still be `int` instead of `void`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Right you are, unless he is coding on an embedded (*freestanding*) system without an OS, it's all implementation defined there. See [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)